# Vector object initialisation

Tags: c++, windows, vector

I've been wandering on the internet trying to solve some problem in my program. I can't find suffisent information on the Vector object in the documentation about the standards.

So, my question is : what is the default value affected to a newly created Vector object using the default constructor ?

Comment: I don't know where you're looking, but it's perfectly clear [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: What do you mean by the default value? The vector is created empty.

Comment: I mean the default value returned by "::size()"

Comment: The vector is empty, it dont have any value, if you try to access anything using at an exception will be trow. You can check that with yourVector.size() and you can use an iterator to run trough it or use the at + size.

Comment: What about the "::capacity()" value then ?

Comment: I'm sure all your questions can be explained by visiting [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @Xaltar The value of the vector's capacity is specified. It is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean `std::vector`, then the default constructor constructs an empty vector, with 0 elements in it.